# Convert SCSS to CSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm following a tutorial that uses SCSS which I'm not using in my application. I want to convert the SCSS below into CSS. When I use a site like SassMeister I get an error that says "undefined mixin 'transition'"

How can I convert this to CSS?

```
.main-view-container{
    // Animations for the separate UI Views
    &.ng-enter,
    &.ng-leave{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    &.ng-enter{
        @include transition(.2s ease-out all .2s);
    }

    &.ng-leave{
        @include transition(.2s ease-out all);
    }

    &.ng-enter,
    &.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{
        @include opacity(0);
    }

    &.ng-leave,
    &.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{
        @include opacity(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@import "compass";` at the beginning of your `SCSS` code snippet, so you can use the mixins provided by [compass framework](http://compass-style.org/).

By the way, SassMeister supports many SCSS Extensions

```
Ark  (v0.2.0)
Base.Sass  (v1.6.0)
Bitters  (v0.10.0)
Blend Modes  (v0.0.2)
Bootstrap Sass  (v3.3.3)
Bourbon  (v4.2.0)
Box  (v0.1.2)
Breakpoint  (v2.5.0)
Breakpoint Slicer  (v1.3.6)
Breakup  (v1.0.2)
CSShake  (v616a877957)
Ceasar Easing  (v0.7)
Color Hacker  (v1.0.0)
Color Schemer  (v0.2.8)
ColorMeSass  (vfd9afc6c1f)
Compass  (v1.0.3)
Compass Inuit  (v5.0.2)
Compass Placeholders  (v1.1.1)
Compass Slideshow  (v0.2.0)
Fancy Buttons  (v1.2.0)
Fittext  (v0.0.5)
Flint  (v2.1.2)
Foundation  (v5.5.1)
Garnish  (v0.2.1)
Grid Coordinates  (v1.2.0)
Guff  (v1.0.0)
Harsh  (v1.0.0)
Include Media  (v1.1.2)
Jacket  (v1.0.0)
Jeet  (v6.1.2)
Juice  (v1.0.0)
MathSass  (v0.9.5)
Modular Scale  (v2.0.6)
Neat  (v1.6.0)
Normalize SCSS  (v3.0.2)
Photoshop Drop Shadow  (v0.0.1)
Position  (v0.2.14)
Quotation Marks  (v0.1.1)
Responsive Calculator  (v0.0.2)
Responsive Modular Scale  (v0.2.1)
Responsive Sass  (v0.1.1)
Salsa  (v0.0.1)
Sass A11Y  (v0.1.0)
Sass Color Helpers  (v2.0.0)
Sassifaction  (v0.0.4)
Sassy Buttons  (v0.2.6)
Sassy Maps  (v0.4.0)
Sassy Text Shadow  (v0.0.4)
Sassy-Gridlover  (v1.1.0)
Sassy-Math  (v1.5.1)
SassyBitwise  (v1.1.2)
SassyCast  (v1.1.1)
SassyJSON  (v1.1.8)
SassyLists  (v2.2.1)
SassyMatrix  (v1.0.1)
SassySort  (v1.0.0)
SassyStrings  (v1.1.4)
Scut  (v1.1.2)
Singularity Extras  (v1.0.0)
Singularity Quick Spanner  (v0.1.3)
Singularity.gs  (v1.5.1)
Stipe  (v0.0.6.4)
Stitch  (v0.1.4)
Sunglass  (v3.0.5)
Susy  (v2.2.2)
Toolkit  (v2.7.0)
True  (v1.0.1)
Typecsset  (v0.3.0)
Typesettings  (v2.3.3)
UtilityBelt  (v1.1.0)
YIQ Color Contrast  (v1.1.1)
Zen Grids  (v1.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, in SCSS when you wrap things inside of other things, when compiled they just add the parent onto the front. So in normal CSS the above will look like the following:

```
.main-view-container .ng-enter,
.main-view-container .ng-leave {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
}

.main-view-container .ng-enter{
    transition: ease-out all .2s;
}

.main-view-container .ng-leave{
    transition: 2s ease-out all;
}

.main-view-container .ng-enter,
.main-view-container .ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.main-view-container .ng-leave,
.main-view-container .ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You cant use the @includes which are mixins, because regular CSS cant read them.

Comment: Actually SassMeister supports many SCSS extensions, you can make use of them.

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question, I thought the question said that SCSS wasn't being used because of the line "I'm following a tutorial that uses SCSS which I'm not using in my application"

Answer (score 0):

Putting this out there in case it helps anyone-- converting from scss to css via command line.

Simply visit the directory storing the scss file in your terminal, and type:

```
sass --watch filename.scss:filename.css
```

NOTE: This is "watching" for changes to filename.scss, so you may have to do an arbitrary save for it to pick up "changes".

After a short time, it'll complete and auto-populate filename.css (along with filename.css.map) in the same directory.